# Is it possible to determine the size (memory footprint) of an application scoped variable in ColdFusion?

Tags: memory-management, coldfusion, fusionreactor

We use FusionReactor which will show the overall memory usage at the server level,  but it would be useful to be able to see how much memory individual items stored in the application scope are taking up.

Comment: Short answer is you can't directly through CF, instead you've got to work with Java. See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/ or http://www.seefusion.com/

I think both of these server monitors could help you out

Comment: Andy, as I said we do use FusionReactor, but it only tells you how much of the overall allocated memory is being used. You can't drill down to individual items, which is what I'm after. I suspect it's just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

CFSimplicity,

The Enterprise version of ColdFusion 8 and higher has the Server monitor.  The Server Monitor can  breakdown memory usage and find out what requests and what variable scopes are consuming how much memory. FusionReactor currently can not.

According to a post on the FusionReactor group: http://groups.google.com/group/fusionreactor/browse_thread/thread/8a017a61d17e9840/d57cef46b843207d?lnk=gst&q=memory+request#d57cef46b843207d

James Holmes said:

> A CF Standard install could make use
>   of the Java SizeOf() class: 
>   sizeof.sourceforge.net
>    sourceforge.net/projects/sizeof
>   Some custom code would be necessary to
>   create a monitor based on this,  but
>   it does work.  mxAjax / CFAjax docs
>   and other useful articles: 
>   www.bifrost.com.au/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you need to do in real time and/or in production for monitoring? Or is this just something that you need for debugging?

I would suggest just using one of the JVM memory dump tools or maybe launching your app with the JRockit jvm and doing some live analysis with that.

http://www.schierberl.com/blog/coldfusion-memory-leaks-part-i-profiler-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see the Application Scope size from ColdFusion, using FusionReactor Application Performance Monitor http://www.fusion-reactor.com - this information is currently captured and stored in one of the log files.   It is also possible to visualize this information using FusionAnalytics - which is able to display and analyze the metrics which have been captured from FusionReactor.  You can see an example of this here - http://docs.intergral.com/display/FA205/CF+Scope+Sizes

Comment: Seems to show the size of the overall scope, but I was really looking for a way to see how much memory individual variables were using. Thanks for the info though.